# Scala: How can I write length of ByteArray and then the ByteArray itself to sequence files?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have an HDFS file which has several records.

1. I want to be able to write the size of each record and then the record itself.
2. How can I do the above and then `saveAsSequenceFile`?

Note: The records are in byteArray format

Comment: Please update the question with what you've tried so far.

Comment: A record being each line? Do you want to read a file on HDFS line by line and then save the output as `length(line), line`?